# In Lua, what are the different forms to print?

Tags: lua

I'm learning Lua, and I want to know the difference of `print()` and `=` or `print()` and `io.write()`.

Comment: `=` is only for the interactive mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` is used for outputting text messages. It joins its arguments with a tab character, and automatically inserts a newline.

`io.write` is more simple. While it also accepts any number of arguments, it simply concatenates them (without inserting any characters) and doesn't add any newline. Think of it as `file:write` applied to the standard output.

These lines are equivalent:

```
io.write("abc")
io.write("a", "b", "c")
io.write("a") io.write("b") io.write("c")
```

I'd recommend using `print` for outputting normal text messages, or for debug, and `io.write` when you either want to print a number of strings without concatenating them explicitly (using `io.write` saves more memory), be able to write parts of a text separately, or outputting binary data via strings.

Answer (score 5):

This short paragraph from "Programming in Lua" explains some differences:

> ### 21.1 The Simple I/O Model
>
> Unlike `print`, `write` adds no extra characters to the output, such as
>   tabs or newlines. Moreover, `write` uses the current output file,
>   whereas `print` always uses the standard output. Finally, `print`
>   automatically applies `tostring` to its arguments, so it can also show
>   tables, functions, and `nil`.

There is also following recommendation:

> As a rule, you should use print for quick-and-dirty programs, or for
>   debugging, and write when you need full control over your output

Essentially, `io.write` calls a `write` method using current output file, making `io.write(x)` equivalent to `io.output():write(x)`.

And since `print` can only write data to the standard output, its usage is obviously limited. At the same time this guarantees that message always goes to the standard output, so you don't accidently mess up some file content, making it a better choice for debug output.

Another difference is in return value: `print` returns `nil`, while `io.write` returns file handle. This allows you to chain writes like that:

```
io.write('Hello '):write('world\n')
```